# Виртуальная машина Java и POSIX

Tags: jvm, java

Мне, как новичку в программировании, не понятно как работает в `UNIX'ах` (да и не только в них) вируальная машина `Java`. Например, `Linux` написан, в основном, на `С`. Для обращения к нему имеются системные вызовы в виде библиотечных функций. Получается, что `Java`-код преобразуется в байт-код, потом в `си` код ? Но это как-то глуповато. К тому же, во всех книгах говорится, что байт-код преобразуется сразу в машинный. Но если это так, то как тогда совершаются системные вызовы, которые являеются `си`-библиотеками ?

У меня сейчас в голове такая путаница по этому вопросу... Может ли кто-то разложить все по полочкам простым языком ?

Comment: C-библиотека это библиотека уже в машинном коде. А C-библиотекой она называется только потому, что сама написана на C и придерживается C-шного соглашения о вызове. Вызов же можно сделать из произвольного языка который способен сгенерить машинный код для этого.

Comment: Да, но что происходит между тем как Java-код стал байт-кодом и моментом вызова асм-кода ? То есть, байт-код же не может дергать системные вызовы, ведь так ? Как все это работает тогда ?

Comment: По хорошему байт код сам ничего делать не может, ибо процессор не подозревает что это такое. пути два: либо машина интерпретирует байт-код и сразу выполняет - т.е. видит "вызови открытие файла" и сама делает соответствующие `push` и затем `int 80h`, хотя т.к. сама машина написана на C, она скорее всего делает `call fopen` из libc. Второй вариант - байт код явно преобразуется в написанные вызовы и в итоге сам выполняется на процессоре

Comment: Т.е. по сути первые java машины были программно реализованным процессором, понимающим байт-код. современные версии являются скорее компиляторами байт кода в машинный

Comment: Не понимаю тогда как машинный код из `jre` попадает в регистры процессора. Ведь между процессором и `jre` существует огромнейший слой - операционная система. Она не даст простому процессу (а виртуальная машина таким процессом и является с точки зрения ОС) рулить регистрами процессора. Поэтому, мне кажется, оба ваши предположения не являются правильными. Либо я их не правильно интерпретировал.

Comment: Современные Java машины являются смесью компилятора и интерпретатора, они оптимизированы на эффективное выполнение байткода с точки зрения скорости и ресурсов. Вкратце, все работает так: исходный код -> компиляция (получается байткод) -> выполнение в java машине -> преобразование байткода в нативный код платформы (это задача jvm) -> выполнение нативного кода. Напрямую из байткода Вы не сможете управолять "регистрами процессора", этим будет заниматься jvm, получая инструкции из Вашего байт-кода. Инструкции не машинные, а специальные (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/jvms8.pdf)

Comment: @faoxis Как это ОС не даст рулить регистрами. А как по вашему работают те же C-шные программы, ведь компилятор из них делает машинный код, который непосредственно "рулит регистрами". Да, конечно он выполняется на уровне PL3 и если он попытается сделать что то недопустимое с точки зрения ОС произойдет нарушение общей защиты которое ОС обработает и примет меры (подгрузит страницу, сэмулирует как то или аварийно завершит приложение). Точно так же это касается и java машины, куски ее кода и кода который она создает выполняется непосредственно процессором

Comment: @Mike я хотел сказать, что далеко не все операции можно выполнять в режиме пользователя и для многих нужен режим ядра. Если отправлять напряму процессору асмовские инструкции, то это уже получается программирование без участия ОС.

Comment: Почему это. вы видимо не представляете как работают современные процессоры. любой код, включая и пользовательское приложение непосредственно обрабатывается процессором. ОС для его выполнения не требуется. Но сегменты кода пользовательского процесса помечены в дескрипторе уровнем привилегий PL3 и если код находящийся в таком сегменте попытается обратится куда не следует или вызовет какую нибудь привелегированную операцию то он будет остановлен и будет вызван обработчик int 13 из кода ядра, который примет меры

Comment: @Mike хм... вы правы, я не знаю как работают современные процессоры... такой вопрос... зачем ОС тогда вообще нужна ?

Comment: ОС... вот ее код как раз находится на уровне привилегий PL0 т.е. может выполнять что угодно и он как раз выдает сегменты и страницы приложениям так, что бы они не мешали друг другу. Так же работает с аппаратурой, по таймеру передает управление от одной задачи к другой и обрабатывает запросы приложений на привилегированные операции. ну и еще кучу другой работы. Сам процессор устроен таким образом что бы обработчик ОС вызывался каждый раз когда приложению что то понадобилось или оно полезло куда не следует

Comment: Я тогда вообще ничего не понимаю. В книге Таненбаума "Современные операционные системы" говорится, что ОС предоставляет программам api в виде библиотек для взаимодействия с железом через системные вызовы. Вы говорите (как я понимаю, могу ошибаться), что программа напрямую работает с процессором, и с ОС может даже не взаимодействовать до определенного момента. Мой мир представления архитектуры компьютера построен на 4 уровнях (снизу вверх): железо, ОС, прикладные программы, интерфейс взаимодействия пользователя с прикладными программами (например, через графику). В чем я ошибаюсь ?

Answer (score -1):

jvm является "посредником" между байткодом и операционной системой. Грубо говоря, байткод это более компактная запись java кода (лучше подходящая для обработки компьютером). jvm берет команды из байткода и последовательно их выполняет.